# Problema al crear proyectos Ionic Cordova

Tags: ionic, cordova, terminal

cuando me quiero crear un proyecto me sale un error
Yo lo creo con el comando

```
ionic start [nombreproyecto] blank
```

Con la terminal de Windows, me crea el proyecto pero no me sirve ya que con el error no me deja mas anadir pantallas y eso, el error esta en la siguiente foto 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si saben de alguna solucion, o si hay que reinstalar algo me dicen por favor

Comment: Intentaste borrar la cache: **npm cache clean --force**

Comment: Gracias a eso me funciono, gracias!